# How to solve $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + x + \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}- \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\right)} = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimal-control

I'm solving this problem of optimal control using the dynamic programming:
$$
\begin{cases}
\min \displaystyle \int_0^2(x-u)dt + x(2) \\
\dot x = 1+u^2 \\
x(0) = 1
\end{cases}
$$

Then solving the Bellman-Hamilton-Jacobi equation I found the following PDE:
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + x + \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}- \frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\right)} = 0$$

The problem gives an hint: In order to solve BHJ equation, we suggest to find the solution in the family of functions $\mathcal{F} = \{V(t,x) = A +Bt + Ct^2 + D\log(3-t) + E(3-t)x\}$ where $A,B,C,D,E$ are all real costants.

My question is:

> How can someone derives that all the solution of the BHJ equation are in that family of functions? In other words, how could I manage to solve the BHJ without any hint?

Comment: Taking an ansatz (this is very often the best approach to find *some* analytical solutions to non-linear PDEs) $V = f(t) + xg(t)$, i.e. assuming $V$ is linear in $x$, and inserting it into the PDE you can solve for $f,g$ and you should get the given family of solution.

Comment: Great. Can I ask you some reference how to find *all* the solution of a PDE?

Comment: I can't. Non-linear PDEs like this are notoriously hard to solve. One reason is that we cannot just find some simple solutions and then build up more complicated ones from those like we can for linear equations (a sum of two solutions is not a solution) and having derivatives in the denominator is not easy to deal with. Its therefore much less general theory for how to solve them and only some classes of equations have that and often require particular transformation that don't work in general. Don't know for this one, maybe someone else sees some nice trick here.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think you might have a typo in the PDE. Namely I got $1/4$ instead of $1/2$ in front of the last term.

Comment: You are right. I just remade the calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that this problem can be more easily solved using [Pontryagin's maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin%27s_maximum_principle), which gives the following Hamiltonian

$$
H(t,x,\lambda) = x - u + \lambda\,(1 + u^2),
$$

such that

$$
\dot{\lambda} = -1, \quad u = \frac{1}{2\,\lambda}
$$

and from the terminal cost is follows that $\lambda(2) = 1$. In this case solving for the co-state as a function of time is easy, namely $\lambda(t) = 3 - t$ and thus

$$
u(t) = \frac{1}{2\,(3 - t)}. \tag{1}
$$

Note that this solution is still independent of $x(0)$.

---

When formulating the PDE one also obtains that

$$
u = \frac{1}{2\,V_x}, \tag{2}
$$

with $V_x$ shorthand notation for the partial derivative of $V(t,x)$ with respect to $x$. Equating $(2)$ to $(1)$ yields

$$
V_x = 3 - t. \tag{3}
$$

Therefore, the final expression for $V(t,x)$ should be of the form

$$
V(t,x) = x\,(3 - t) + U(t), \tag{4}
$$

with $U(t)$ a yet unknown function of only $t$ and no $x$. Substituting $(4)$ together with $(3)$ in the PDE yields

\begin{align}
0 &= -x + \dot{U} + x + 3 - t - \frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{3 - t}, \\
&= \dot{U} + 3 - t - \frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{3 - t}.
\end{align}

From this it becomes hopefully clear where the function family comes from. Namely, the last term is derived from $(3)$, the second order polynomial comes from integrating $t - 3$ and the logarithm from integrating $(3 - t)^{-1}$.

I am not sure how one could spot this family of functions without Pontryagin's maximum principle. Though, I suspect this is also why the exercise gave the function family, because solving nonlinear PDE's is hard.

Comment: This is what I was searching for. Thank you.